# Difference of a true enclave and an enclave which is not an true enclave

Tags: territory

I learned what an enclave is, but I cannot still understand what is the difference between a true enclave and an enclave which is not a true enclave.

I thoroughly read the explanation in this article but still cannot understand..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclave_and_exclave#True_enclaves

Comment: A [semi-enclave](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-are-the-three-semi-enclaved-countries-of-the-world.html) is not a true enclave.

Answer (score 3):

An enclave is defined as a governmentally autonomous area that is surrounded by a different governmentally autonomous area. The archetypal example is [Vatican City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City), which is an independent city-state that exists on territory that would otherwise be considered part of Italy.

- A **true enclave** is an autonomous area that is completely enclosed by
  the territory or territorial waters of the surrounding state, such
  that one cannot leave the enclave in any direction without stepping
  on, flying over, or sailing through the territory of the surrounding
  state.
- An **exclave** is an area governed by one state that is separated from
  it and completely surrounded by one or more other states. For instance,
  Gibraltar is an exclave because it is administered by the UK, but
  surrounded by Spanish territory.
- A **semi-enclave** is an autonomous area surrounded on all *land* borders
  by a single state, but which has coastal regions that open on international
  waters. As such, one can leave a semi-enclave by boat or plane without
  crossing into the territory of the surrounding state.
- A **maritime enclave** is a true enclave that happens to be an island
  within the territorial waters of a different state.

Note that any autonomous area that shares a border with at least two states is not considered an enclave, because inhabitants are not required to cross the territory of one particular state to exit their region. This is the main idea behind enclaves, that they are autonomous governments that are dependent on the goodwill of a single nation for all international travel and commerce.

Comment: An exclave is not (necessarily) an enclave : Kaliningrad is an exclave of Russia because it's separate from the main country, yet K is bordered by at least two different countries and the open sea. Also, just my opinion but you could make more explicit that a true enclave needs to be surrounded by **one single** state, not just by foreign territory, as you made clear in the semi-enclave explanation.

Comment: @Gouvernathor: Ah, thanks. that hadn't occurred to me. I'll revise when i get the chance.